# How to change response in to multiple array with unique key in NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I am getting response from MySQL query like this:

```
 [{created_at:'06-23-21, 23:33:43',user_count:1,user:"user1"},{created_at:'06-23-21, 
 20:12:50',user_count:4,user:"user2"},{created_at:'06-23-21, 
 19:04:10',user_count:15,user:"user1"},{created_at:'06-23-21, 
  19:04:10',user_count:26,user:"user2"},{created_at:'06-23-21, 
   16:11:56',user_count:46,user:"user3"}]
```

I wanna want this kind of response.

```
 {
  "data": {
    "time": [
        "06-23-21, 23:33:43",
        "06-23-21, 20:12:50",
        "06-23-21, 19:04:10",
        "06-23-21, 19:04:10",
        "06-23-21, 16:11:56"
    ],
    "user1": [
        1,
        0,
        15,
        0
    ],
    "user2": [
        0,
        4,
        26,
        0
    ],
    "user3": [
        0,
        0,
        0,
        46
    ]
  }
 }
```

When no user at particular time it shows 0 at respective array index.
Kindly guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to make this a fancy one-line solution, but the nature of the user count arrays made it tricky. So this is a few different loops. See inline comments below

```js
const dbdata = [{created_at:'06-23-21, 23:33:43',user_count:1,user:"user1"},{created_at:'06-23-21, 20:12:50',user_count:4,user:"user2"},{created_at:'06-23-21, 19:04:10',user_count:15,user:"user1"},{created_at:'06-23-21, 19:04:10',user_count:26,user:"user2"},{created_at:'06-23-21, 16:11:56',user_count:46,user:"user3"}]

let tmpTime = [], users = {}
// set up time array and user placeholder
dbdata.forEach(a => {
  tmpTime.push(a.created_at);
  if (!users.hasOwnProperty(a.user)) users[a.user] = {}
})
// make sure we have chronology
tmpTime = tmpTime.sort((a,b) => b.localeCompare(a));
// populate users placeholder
dbdata.forEach(a => {
  [...new Set(tmpTime)].forEach(t => Object.keys(users).forEach(u => users[u][t] = 0))
})
// put the user counts together
let formatted = dbdata.reduce((b, a) => {
  b.data[a.user][a.created_at] = a.user_count;
  return b
}, {
  data: {
    time: [...tmpTime],
    ...users
  }
});
// strip the keys from the user arrays
Object.keys(formatted.data).forEach(k => {
  if (k !== 'time') formatted.data[k] = Object.values(formatted.data[k])
})


console.log(formatted)
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort but i need 0 in other user when there user count is not available

Comment: i need equal number of index in users, when there is no count for particular user it will push 0 on index

Comment: @hassan - ok, the solution was reworked and now give the result you want

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```js
let data = [{
        created_at: '06-23-21, 23:33:43',
        user_count: 1,
        user: "user1"
    }, {
        created_at: '06-23-21, 20: 12: 50',
        user_count: 4,
        user: "user2"
    },
    {
        created_at: '06 - 23 - 21, 19: 04: 10',
        user_count: 15,
        user: "user1"
    },
    {
        created_at: '06 - 23 - 21, 19: 04: 10',
        user_count: 26,
        user: "user2"
    },
    {
        created_at: '06 - 23 - 21, 16: 11: 56 ',
        user_count: 46,
        user: "user3"
    }
 ]
let result={time:[],user1:[],user2:[],user3:[]} ;
for (let i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    result.time.push(data[i].created_at);
  
  switch (data[i].user){
    case "user1":
        result.user1.push(data[i].user_count);
      result.user2.push(0);
      result.user3.push(0);
      break;
    case "user2":
        result.user2.push(data[i].user_count);
      result.user1.push(0);
      result.user3.push(0);
      break;
    case "user3":
        result.user3.push(data[i].user_count);
      result.user2.push(0);
      result.user1.push(0);
      break;
  }  
}
console.log(result);
```